# construct a continuous function which vanishes at infinity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I want to construct a continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0 $ and $f$ vanishes at infinity.Can anyone give me some examples,thanks!

Comment: $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{e^z}$

Comment: This example is wrong. $f(2n\pi i)=2n\pi i $ which does not tend to $0$.

Comment: What about $f(z) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z)=z$ for $|z| <1$, $f(z)=\frac z {|z|^{2}}$ if $|z| \geq 1$.